# Insert pictures on Outlook for Mac

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am trying to add pictures in a mail body by adding them to the attachments of the mail item and then adding the sources with the right content id in the html of the mail body.

This is working fine except with Outlook for Mac. In Outlook for Windows and also in the browsers (even safari) the pictures are inserted correctly.

In Outlook for Mac I get blank squares with an error that the file might be moved or removed. When I send the email, the pictures are inserted correctly and the receiver gets a mail with pictures (also looks correct in Sent Items).

This issue only surfaces when composing an email on Outlook for Mac. I am using following code:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(uri,
            assetName,
            { },
            function (asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
                    console.log("Attach action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
                    deferred.reject();
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Attach action successfull");
                    deferred.resolve();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to do a saveAsync() after adding the file? I know a number of settings are not propagated until an email is sent or saved as a draft. Unfortunately I'm unable to set up a test to confirm what affect this will have but it may be worth a try:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(
  function callback(result) {
    // Process the result
  });
```

Comment: saveAsync might work but the best solution is to use requirement set 1.5 and pass the { isInline: true } parameter to denote it is being used inline.

Comment: saveAsync still does not make it to work on Apple. Still the same issue.

Comment: Were you able to try using the `isinline:true` as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use inline images as attachments, you will need to specify `isInline` as true as one of the parameters. This is part of [Requirement Set 1.5](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5#addfileattachmentasyncuri-attachmentname-options-callback) which may not be available on your version of Outlook for Mac. Below is a code snippet with an example.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync
(
    "http://i.imgur.com/WJXklif.png",
    "cute_bird.png",
    {
        isInline: true
    },
    function (asyncResult) {
        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(
            "<p>Here's a cute bird!</p><img src='cid:cute_bird.png'>",
            {
                "coercionType": "html"
            },
            function (asyncResult) { }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Setting isInline on true doesn't make a difference on Apple. still the same issue

Comment: @nick , Inline Image feature is currently available only to Insider Fast/Slow users in mac. What is the Mac outlook build you are using? Also please enroll into insiderFast progam on Outlook Mac to get access to the new features first :  https://products.office.com/en-us/office-insider?tab=Mac#Tabs_section

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility We are currently using Insider Fast on Mac.
Version: 15.38 (170809)